# How to avoid Fatal Error "Cannot redeclare class .." with two different third party scripts

Tags: php, paypal, encapsulation, prestashop-1.6

I have to create a payment module for prestashop. This module use the paypal adaptivepayments-sdk which try to define a class named "Address". But also prestashop itself defines a class with this name. So the paypal-sdk always fails.

First I thought I can solve it with namespaces but I think I would have to edit all the paypal-sdk files. But I don't want to touch prestashop or paypal-sdk files.
My next idea is to encapsulate it with a separate http request, but I want to avoid this because in my eyes this is a terrible practice.

Is there a way to encapsulate the sdk? Or is there any other way to solve this Problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

quick solution:

```
composer install
```

in sdk directory, and then

```
require 'adaptivepayments-sdk-php/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I gave it a try, but unfortunately this don't solve my problem. The "Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Address" still exists. I think the composer don't care about such problems.